# MVVM - How to use a given REST-API dll

Tags: c#, rest, mvvm, mvvm-light

I'm starting to learn MVVM in C# with mvvmlight. From an other project, I have a given (but self-made) REST-API as a dll. This dll I'm trying to use in this new project. It is completly based on this API. I'm unsure about the "model"-part and don't want to repeat myself while coding.

**Problem is like this**: The application has several "plugins/sections". Let's look at a sample like the "groups" section. Now the API defines a groups-Entity-Class with all properties like "groupname, permissions, members". Then, the Application must have a groups model and also a groupsViewModel and a GroupsView for the UI. There, I also must list/show "groupname, permissions, members".

**Question is:** Do I have to redeclare all the properties from the dll-entity-class in the mvvm-model-class? Or what is the best way to use a rest api? Is there any pattern. I read about the Extension Object Pattern. But I have no clue.

Hint: Since the API is written by myself (only classes, no mvvm or other frameworks), I could modify it as needed.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the Repository Pattern: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649690.aspx. Basically you create a repository which does the API calls, and transforms the entities to a format you can use in your view.

If the objects from the API are already sufficient you can simply return them, otherwise convert them in the Repository to something more useful.

In the ViewModel you then simply ask the repository to return the model, and need not to care how and in what format it got them.

Small Example:

```
interface IApiRepository
{
    Task<ObservableCollection<ApiModel>> GetApiModelsAsync();
}

class ApiRepository : IApiRepository
{
    private async Task<ObservableCollection> GetApiModelsAsync()
    {
        var myCollection = new ObservableCollection<ApiModel>();
        var result = await DoMyApiCall();
        foreach (result as item)
        {
            var newModel = new ApiModel();
            newModel.fillFromApi(item);
            myCollection.Add(newModel);
        }
        return myCollection;
    }   
}


class MyViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private readonly IApiRepository _apiRepository;

    public MyViewModel(IApiRepository apiRepository)
    {
        _apiRepository = apiRepository;
        InitializeViewModel();
    }

    private ObservableCollection<ApiModel> _apiModels;
    public ObservableCollection<ApiModel> ApiModels
    {
        get { return _apiModels; }
        set { Set(ref _apiModels, value); }
    }

    private async void InitializeViewModel()
    {
        //as soon as the repo is finished ApiModels will raise the RaisePropertyChanged event
        ApiModels = await _apiRepository.GetApiModelsAsync();
    }
}

//in you ViewModelLocator
SimpleIoC.Default.Register<IApiRepository, ApiRepository>();
SimpleIoC.Default.Register<MyViewModel>();

//construct your viewmodel (with the injected repository)
var vm = SimpleIoc.Default.GetInstance<MyViewModel>();
```

with the help of this pattern you can do some other awesome things:

- if you add a new data source you need only to change the repository and not the ViewModel.
- if you want to test your view (for example in Design Mode) you can inject a `MockApiRepository` which returns sample data instead of doing an API call

Comment: Thanks for your great answer. After reading your post, I read about the pattern and I'm trying to set it up now. When I'm done, I'll post my solution based on your answer. Right now, I'm fighting with dependency injections (in order to get your answer to work in my setup). Thanks!

Comment: I've added two more lines to the sample code which may help you. Basically you register the ViewModels too with the IoC and then let the container construct it. Be careful; the IoC container must be able to inject every argument in the constructor, and it will disregard default values (it will still try to set them explicitly).